# What's the purpose of using a generic Singleton class that'll give you an instance of any class?

Tags: singleton

I have a class that needs to be a singleton, so I started to implement something along these lines (I don't remember my *exact* code but this is the wiki demo implementation)

```
public class Singleton
{
    private static Singleton instance = null;

    private Singleton(){}

    public static Singleton GetInstance() 
    {
       if (instance == null) 
          {
              instance = new Singleton();
          }
            return instance;
    }
}
```

Recently during a code review, my boss said this was improper and provided me with the following class:

```
public class Unique<T>
    where T :class, new() 
{
    private static object _syncRoot = new Object();
    private static volatile T _instance;

    // private constructor
    Unique() { }

    // creates the new instance on the first call
    public static T Instance 
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                lock (_syncRoot)
                {
                    if (_instance == null)
                        _instance = new T();
                }
            }
            return _instance;
        }
    }
}
```

With this, I write `Unique<Singleton>.Instance` to get the single instance of any class. Then he went back and changed my class to not implement the Singleton pattern. Problem is, this class is integral to maintaining data for display on the UI, which he knows. But now anyone could come along and write `var x = new Singleton();` which would completely mess up the UI. I can't make `Singleton`'s constructor anything but public because then accessing it via `Unique` doesn't work.

So, I understand the power and flexibility of his generic class, which is cool and all, but it seems to be unsafe. Am I missing something?

Tagged without a language because I think this is a broader, language independent question but the code posted is C#.

Edit; Actually, I just tested what'd happen if I created a new instance of the class and it didn't ruin the the UI, but if someone inherits this project from me and are unaware of it they might be confused as to why they're writing to this particular class and the data isn't showing up.

Comment: Your boss' implementation is wrong.  http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

Comment: @SLaks Interesting read, thanks for the link. Are you saying his implementation is wrong because he doesn't use `Lazy<T>` as described in the final one? If so, that's probably because we're using .NET 3.5 and this article specifies it was introduced in 4.0

Comment: it's not wrong, but I think what @SLaks's reasoning was - people can't agree on 'volatile' vs. memory barriers, as well as performance isn't as great as the implementations that don't use locks..

Comment: Also, for UI that pattern makes it hard to instantiate a class, in XAML for example. If you use 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity' than you can create a class and ensure Singleton by registering type in container with '_container.RegisterType<IMyView, MyView>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());'